# Structuring TextFixtures in nUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Upon unit testing of some class, there is a need to test same methods for different combination of data in a class. This can be achieved by writing several TextFixtures and repeating same test methods for each one, as below.

```
 [TextFixture]
 public class WhenBuildingLongFoo
 {
     private Foo foo;

     [Setup]
     public void Creating()
     {
          foo = new Foo(){Height = new FooHeight(200)};
     }

     [Test]
     public void ReturnsValidHeight()
     {
     Assert.AreEqual(200, foo.Height);
     }
  }

  [TextFixture]
  public class WhenBuildingShortFoo
  {
  private Foo foo;
  [SetUp]
  public void Creating()
  {
       foo = new Foo(){Height=newFooHeight(2);
   }
   [Test]
   public void ReturnsValidHeight()
   {
        Assert.AreEqual(2, foo.Height);
    }
}
```

1. What is the best way to structure such fixtures, so that method ReturnsValidHeight is written only once?

I came up with creating a public static class Utilities in a common namespace, which has this method; but could you please advise something better?

Something like create an abstract class with such method and then derive fixtures from it?

2. How to reuse setup among fixtures, just varying values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TestCase` attribute to run the same test with different input values. That'll reduce a lot of your duplicate code. The `SetUp` method isn't necessary in your case either.

```
[TextFixture]
public class FooTests
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase(200)]
    [TestCase(2)]
    public void ReturnsValidHeight(int expectedHeight)
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Height = new FooHeight(expectedHeight) };

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedHeight, foo.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. The [SetUp] attribute has its disadvantages. For example, it physically separates part of the test code. It's a good heuristic to treat each and every test as a "tiny universe all in itself" without having to scan for a possible SetUp method. You can often replace SetUp methods with in-test method calls to a Builder or something similar which allows for much more flexiblility (i.e. does every test need _exactly_ the same SetUp?).

Answer (score 0):

You might ckeck this library as an alternative for tests writing:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Heleonix.Testing.NUnit/
You describe your tests in AAA or GWT styles in a way JavaScript's Jasmine or Jest do.
You tests become more readable and easier in support. With TestCase attributes you might end up with complex tests, which would be hard to understand even in few months